# Rails - Ruby enumerable select by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Expense model I have a date attribute called payment_date.  This is a Date format and not DateTime.

In one of my views Im displaying this data in a few different formats. and I want to avoid multiple queries.

For example, right next to `Expense.all` I need to display expenses year to date.  Rather than running two queries to pull essentially the same information, I thought I would try to pluck the YTD data from `@expenses = Expense.all`.

Right now I'm trying to use:

`@expenses.select { |ex| ex.payment_date > Date.today.beginning_of_year }`

but this is returning a blank array.

Is it possible to select results by date, and where am i messing up?

Comment: What database are you using for your application?

Comment: sanity check: what's the value of `@expenses.last.payment_date` (assuming you're ordering by date)?

Comment: @acobster `Expense.order('payment_date desc').last.payment_date`  returns 'Thu, 19 Jan 2006',

Comment: @yez Im using Postgres

Comment: Well there ya go...ain't no payments this year. It's working correctly! Try inserting some payments after 2016-01-01 and see if you're still getting an empty array. :)

Comment: wait a minute! `Expense.order('payment_date desc').first.payment_date` returns Fri, 01 Jan 2016, I knew something didn't smell right.

Comment: Try `>=` instead of `>` in your `select` block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To include Jan 1 of this year in your YTD expenses, use `>=` instead of `>` in your `select` block.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this with Rails, an even more performant way to query this is by using ActiveRecord/SQL.

If you have many records, doing `@expenses = Expense.all` and then using the Ruby enumerable `select` on that collection will load all of the expenses from the DB into memory. This could be quite slow, or could even cause out-of-memory errors!

You can do (assuming the DB is Postgres):

```
@ytd_expenses = Expense.where("payment_date >= ?", Date.today.beginning_of_year)
```

This will only return the results you care about from the DB.